# Type error when calling a function from another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to pass a function to another component in order to call it up there after a button is clicked. When I run the code below I get an error.

```
 const [downloadUrls, setDownloadUrls] = useState<string[]>([]);
 const [preview, setPreview] = useState<string[]>([]);

 let promises: any[] = [];

 const uploadingToFB = async () => {

 setLoading(true);
 try {
  for (let i = 0; i < preview.length; i++) {
    const productRef = ref(storage, `images/${uuidv4()}.jpg`);

    promises.push(
      new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          uploadString(productRef, preview[i], "data_url").then(
            (snapshot) => {
              getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then(async (url) => {
                resolve(url);
              });
            }
          );
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  await Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
    setDownloadUrls(values);
    setLoading(false);
  });
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }

}

  <ButtonSaveProduct uploadingToFB={uploadingToFB}></ButtonSaveProduct>
```

ButtonSaveProduct Component:

```
 import React from "react";

 type PAGEPROPS = {
  uploadingToFB: () => Promise<void>;
 };


 export default function ButtonSaveProduct({ uploadingToFB }: PAGEPROPS) {
 return (
  <button
  className="p-4 bg-blue-950 text-white rounded-md hover:bg-blue-200"
  onClick={uploadingToFB}>
  save
  </button>
 );
}
```

> Type 'OmitWithTag<PAGEPROPS, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
> Property 'uploadingToFB' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'never'.

On Vercel i got:

> Type error: Page "app/ButtonSaveProduct/page.tsx" has an invalid "default" export:
> Type "{ uploadingToFB: () => void; }" is not valid

Comment: does nobody have an idea?

Comment: Firstly your uploadingToFB does not return void, it is an async function so the return type is Promise<void>. Secondly the onClick should be calling the function rather than the result of the function so `onClick={uploadingToFb}`. Try that and let us know

Comment: Hey, no i got   Property 'uploadingToFB' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Comment: Where is `promises` defined? What is `uploadString`? What is `ref`? What is `PageProps`? Because you've defined a type `PAGEPROPS` but your error message mentions a `PageProps` which you don't show. Why are you using a [well-known antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) all over the place? Your try/catch won't work because of the way you've nested the Promises. I realize that isn't what you're asking about here but it's going to be hard to figure out the actual problem without the needed info/fixes.

Comment: @Jared Smith i have edit my orginal post- uploadString, ref are Firebase functions.

Comment: You can't have mutable state like that in a functional component. And you don't need it AFAICT. We aren't going to be able to help you with this, you need to fix the problems in the code I mentioned earlier and add all the relevant data.